# How to show that the inequality is true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $ (a_n)_{n \geq 1}$  be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Assume that  $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\epsilon > 0$ and for all $n > N$ the following is true: $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$.

Show that for all $n > N$ the following inequality is true:

$ \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^n a_k -a\right| \leq \epsilon + \frac{N}{n} |a|$

I tried the following:

$\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n-1} a_k +\frac{1}{n}a_n - a\right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n-1} a_k \right|+\left|\frac{1}{n}a_n - a\right| $

I also know:

$\left|\frac{1}{n}a_n - a\right| + \left| \frac{n-1}{n}a_n \right| \geq \left| a_n-a 
\right|$

So:

$\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n-1} a_k \right|+\left|\frac{1}{n}a_n - a\right| < \left|\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n-1} a_k\right| + \epsilon -\left| \frac{n-1}{n} a_n \right|$

But I don't know how to continue from there. I would very much appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\left|\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=N+1}^n a_k}{n} - a\right| = \left|\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=N+1}^n (a_k - a)}{n} + \dfrac{(n - N)a}{n} - a\right| = \left|\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=N+1}^n (a_k - a)}{n} - \dfrac{Na}{n}\right| < \left|\dfrac{(n - N)\epsilon}{n}\right| + \dfrac{N}{n}\cdot |a| < \epsilon + \dfrac{N}{n}\cdot |a|$